# Зачем подключать header файлы в файлах исходного кода C++

Tags: c++

У меня есть файл main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "function.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << add(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Файл function.h:

```cpp
int add(int a, int b);
```

Файл function.cpp:

```
#include "function.h" // ЗАЧЕМ НУЖНО ПОДКЛЮЧАТЬ function.h?

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Как я знаю, в .cpp файлах нужно подключать соответствующий .h файл. Если убрать `#include "function.h"` в файле function.cpp, то программа также будет работать, т.к. компилятор сам находит определение функции.

Объясните пожалуйста, для чего его нужно подключать, для чего так делают?

Comment: В таком, как у вас, тривиальном случае, только с целью самопроверки. Т.е. проверяете, что прототип функции в .h совпадает с ее определением в .cpp

Comment: Благодарю! А какие ещё есть случаи, когда это нужно?

Comment: Когда общие описания прототипов функций и структур данных используются во многих .cpp файлах

Comment: Всё, теперь дошло. Ещё раз спасибо. Можете оформить Ваш комментарий, как ответ, я бы поставил галочку.

Comment: Ну а если кроме этой функции в function.h есть еще какое то пространство имен(или класс)  'X' имеющий имя  'A', определение которого нужно вывести в  файл function.cpp:?.. Откуда этому файлу знать что такое X::A, если не подключен заголовочный?(добавление к вышесказанному)